# Should i use if-else or switch

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

I have Abstract Class with two abstract methods.
I also have 4 classes that extend that class and also override those methods.

The task is to "if possible optimize code" in those 4 classes.

There are two types of same override method

First

```
    protected boolean canApprove(int id, double cost, Type type) {
        boolean result = false;

        if (type == Type.CONSUMABLES && cost < 300) {
            result = true;
            return result;
        } else if (type == Type.CLERICAL && cost < 500) {
            result = false;
            return result;
        } else if (type == Type.GADGETS && cost < 1000) {
            result = true;
            return result;
        } else if (type == Type.GAMING && cost < 2000) {
            result = true;
            return result;
        } else if (type == Type.PC && cost < 5000) {
            result = true;
            return result;
        } else {
            result = false;
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Second

```
protected boolean canApprove(int id, double cost, Type type) {
        boolean result = false;

        switch (type) {
            case CONSUMABLES:
                if (cost < 300) {
                    result = true;
                    return result;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            case CLERICAL:
                if (cost < 500) {
                    result = true;
                    return result;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            case GADGETS:
                if (cost < 1000) {
                    result = true;
                    return result;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            case GAMING:
                if (cost < 2000) {
                    result = true;
                    return result;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            case PC:
                if (cost < 5000) {
                    result = true;
                    return result;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            default:
                result = false;
                return result;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

My Question is which i should use or if there is a better way?

I dont know what method is the best to use?

Comment: You have a typo in the first example `result = false` instead of `true` for the clerical type.

Comment: similar question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74210115/what-code-is-more-optimized-if-or-switch) (now deleted) - with similar typo, see previous comment (as far as I remember)  {and my comment as answer here, more conditions!}

Comment: alternative using switch expression: `return switch (type) { case CONSUMABLES -> cost<300; case CLERICAL -> cost<500; case ... default -> false; }`

Comment: @user16320675 Nice! Or maybe even pull the comparison out `return cost < switch(type) {case CONSUMABLES -> 300; ... } `

Answer (score 1):

Neither.

```
return (type == Type.CONSUMABLES && cost < 300)
    || (type == Type.CLERICAL && cost < 500)
    || (type == Type.GADGETS && cost < 1000)
    || (type == Type.GAMING && cost < 2000)
    || (type == Type.PC && cost < 5000);
```

Comment: It is slower then second example. `switch` jumps straight to required case, your code will check types one by one until it find correct one.

Comment: @talex Premature optimization. Write code that's easy to read. If it's a proven performance bottleneck, optimize it.

Comment: Question was specifically about optimization

Comment: if you think this question about readability you should have voted to close it, because it is subjective, therefore opinion based.

Comment: if you not sure what it is about you should have voted to close as "need more focus"

Comment: @talex "Focussed" does not mean there is absolutely no room for interpretation. This conversation is not productive.

Comment: @Michael it is not premature optimization when you implement something with a known  and widely accepted optimization. Otherwise, why not implement everything with "brute force"? And talex is 100% correct: this question was SPECIFICALLY about optimization. LOL

Comment: @talex, could you read my answer and tell me if you agree with my conclusion?

Comment: @hfontanez I fully agree with your first sentence. Rest is pretty much irrelevant to the topic after that, but if you insist. "In my opinion, not much" is unsubstantiated claim. To be honest you attempt impossible task deciding is it much or not without clearly defining criteria for an answer. Rest is indeed opinion based so I don't see a point of expressing my personal preferences. Hope my comment helps.

Comment: @talex I was specifically asking about my conclusion and to why I disagree with this community wiki post.

Comment: @hfontanez whole discussion is pointless because question is rightfully closed. community post isn't anything special. Anyone can create it. In current situation I don't think it should be community answer, but I don't think any of that answer should even exists, so... :)

Comment: @talex, as I predicted, it was going to be closed for being opinion-based.

Answer (score 0):

In your case all the switch cases have common logic which can be implemented as `isCostWithinLimit` method.

```
private boolean isCostWithinLimit(double cost, double limit) {
    return cost < limit;
}
```

As it is pointed out by @hfontanez, it is a opinion-based question, you can decide this type of issue on case-by-case basic.

However, I have implemented this using switch in 2 ways

Using switch statement:

```
protected boolean canApprove(int id, double cost, Type type) {

    switch (type) {
        case CONSUMABLES:
            return isCostWithinLimit(cost, 300);
        case CLERICAL:
            return isCostWithinLimit(cost, 500);
        case GADGETS:
            return isCostWithinLimit(cost, 1000);
        case GAMING:
            return isCostWithinLimit(cost, 2000);
        case PC:
            return isCostWithinLimit(cost, 5000);
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

Using switch expression:

```
protected boolean canApprove(int id, double cost, Type type) {

    return switch (type) {
        case CONSUMABLES -> isCostWithinLimit(cost, 300);
        case CLERICAL -> isCostWithinLimit(cost, 500);
        case GADGETS -> isCostWithinLimit(cost, 1000);
        case GAMING -> isCostWithinLimit(cost, 2000);
        case PC -> isCostWithinLimit(cost, 5000);
    };
}
```

Comment: Good answer! Can you update your answer to explain switch expressions and Java version constraints? Thanks